# Insert rows into a table from updated rows in another table TRIGGER

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert, sql-update

I have 2 regular tables (Table1 and Table2) and a temporary table (TempTable). I'm updating the rows in Table1 from the rows in Table2:

```
update t1
set t1.[Table1] = t2.[Price]
FROM
[Table1] t1
JOIN [Table2] t2 on t1.[KAT_ID] = t2.            
[KAT_ID]
where t1.[Price] != t2.[Price]
```

I want to create a trigger on Table1 that inserts ALL OF THE UPDATED ROWS into TempTable. This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TABLE1_TRIGGER] ON [dbo].[Table1]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE 
##TempTable
CREATE TABLE ##TempTable(
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[KAT_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Price] [money] NULL)
```

I have no idea how to go about inserting the updated rows into TempTable.

Comment: Why do you want to insert these into a Global temporary Table? These are, honestly, awful. You would be better placeing it into some kind of staging table, or something. What is your full goal here?

Comment: It looks like an XY problem

Comment: What records do you want to insert , before modifications(Old values) or after modification (new values).?

Comment: what is the necessity of inserting the Log data into a Global temp temple .  Scope of temp table is not forever . you better think of physical table .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be far better putting your data in a staging table of some kind, rather than a global temporary table. As I said in the comment, they perform terribly.

Firstly, we'll start with some kind of staging table. I don't know what your set up is, so we'll put in a schema for it as well:

```
CREATE SCHEMA staging;
CREATE TABLE staging.[RelevantNameHere] (ID bigint IDENTITY(1,1),
                                         KAT_ID varchar(50),
                                         Price money);
GO
```

Then we can move onto the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TABLE1_TRIGGER] ON [dbo].[Table1]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
    TRUNCATE TABLE staging.[RelevantNameHere];

    INSERT INTO [RelevantNameHere] (KAT_ID, Price)
    SELECT i.KAT_ID, i.Price
    --In a trigger such as this, there are 2 additional objects you can refer to
    --[inserted] and [deleted]. The names are a give away as to what they contain.
    FROM inserted i; 
GO
```

Of course, this is working on the very limited information we have here. I very much doubt that the problem you have described is actually the problem you have. You would probably be better explaining your full goal and aims are in your post; there could well be a far better answer out there than the above.

Answer (score 0):

I guess below is the query you are looking for .

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[TABLE1_TRIGGER] ON [dbo].[Table1]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##TempTable') IS NOT NULL 
DROP TABLE ##TempTable

CREATE TABLE ##TempTable(
[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[KAT_ID] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Price] [money] NULL)

INSERT INTO ##TempTable (KAT_ID,Price)

SELECT KAT_ID,Price FROM [INSERTED]
```

Comment: You made a comment  on the question of not using a Global Temporary table, but have used one in your answer. Isn't this a bit contradictory?

Comment: As per the OP requirement i have used temp table (Should be changed by OP as per his need) .But its not the good practice to use Temp tables.